# RecyclerView listen to item added

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and I use the following line to add new items:

```
recyclerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(newItemIndex);
```

Is there a listener I can use to know when the RecyclerView has finished adding the item?

Comment: I want to do something on the newly added View.

Comment: you have the index, you can set tag to the newly added view and findViewWithTag

Comment: what do you want to do with the item?

Answer (score 10):

I would try creating a subclass of the `DefaultItemAnimator` overriding the `onAddFinished` method.

```
public class MyDefaultItemAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {

  @Override public void onAddFinished(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {
    super.onAddFinished(item);

    String text = "Add element: " + item.getPosition();
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

And then:

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new MyDefaultItemAnimator());
```

In this way you should be notified of when the add animation finished.