# Is there an existing method that listens for a RecyclerView item change?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Let's say I have a `RecyclerView`, and when it loads data from the databse, I want to do something. I'd imagine it like this:

```
recyclerView.setOnUpdateListener(new OnUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                //I do whatever I want
            }
        };
```

---

**What I've seen:**

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633654/recyclerview-listen-to-item-added) link but the question isn't too clear; and neither is the answer as it doesn't explain what's it doing. And it's pretty old.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175381/implement-load-more-listener-in-expandable-recyclerview) but it isn't answered yet.

---

**Why?**

Because I am loading data from the Database, and I want to show a progress circle while it's loading, and dismiss it when data shows.

**Note:** I am using a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver.html).

like this:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = ...
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        //Do some task.
    }
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Do I have to add all those overrided methods? Or can I just override onChanged?

Comment: `RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver` is abstract class. So you just overried onChanged. I updated my answer.